# PostgreSQL to MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, duplicates, syntax-error

Hello there phpmyadmin returns an error of the following because it's postgreSQL and i need to migrate it to MySQL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ORDID
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 622
;

CREATE SEQUENCE PRODID
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 200381
;

CREATE SEQUENCE CUSTID
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 109
;
```

what is the equivalent syntax for the CREATE SEQUENCE?

Comment: Do you have an index on another table called `PRICE_INDEX` ?

Comment: does your create table succeed? maybe you already have a table called price, can you try to drop it first and then recreate it?

Comment: there was a
      CREATE INDEX PRICE_INDEX ON PRICE(PRODID, STARTDATE);
hided by my teacher, thanks!

Comment: still not running, if i delete one of them i get a syntax error.

Comment: What is the new error?

Comment: the new error is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEQUENCE ORDID
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 622' at line 1.

Comment: SQL query: CREATE SEQUENCE ORDID INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 622. this is all it says.

Comment: Ifound there are also some problems with the sequences: CREATE SEQUENCE ORDID
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 622
;

CREATE SEQUENCE PRODID
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 200381
;

CREATE SEQUENCE CUSTID
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 109
;'

Comment: @Strawberry It's not mysql, it's postgre sql and i'm trying to migrate it to mysql for an assignment.

Comment: This is probably the single most important point of the question. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a sequence object like PostresSQL does. The (sort of) equivalent syntax would be to define an auto-incrementing column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, a definition for such a table might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE price
(prodid INT NOT NULL 
,stdprice DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL
,minprice DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL
,startdate DATE NOT NULL 
,enddate DATE
,PRIMARY KEY (prodid,startdate)
);
```

If you wanted a surrogate key, you could add `price_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` to the above definition, and define the compound PRIMARY KEY as a UNIQUE KEY instead